# Using "Select by Location" in ArcGIS ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, select-by-location

I need some assistance for my workflow in ArcGIS ModelBuilder. I have two datasets:

1. Points (unique ID field: "bldg_id")
2. Parcels

I am trying to select Parcels within a certain distance (e.g., within 100 m) from the Points feature. There are several entities within the Points feature. The selected Parcels may sometimes overlap with each other for certain Points. I then want to output the selected Parcels into a new feature class.

My model has been successful up to a point, and I need assistance.

I am able to output each Parcels into a new shapefile based on the "bldg_id" field (%VALUE%) in the Points feature. In other words, if there are 10 unique "bldg_id" values, I get 10 unique parcel outputs called "Output_BldgID_%VALUE%." However, I want to merge all these individual outputs into one single output with a new field ID that identifies the corresponding BldgID (%VALUE%).

I am using the "MERGE" tool, but I don't know how to generate the unique field ID. My full dataset is several hundred points, so dealing with 100+ feature classes would be unwieldy. As a result, I want one single feature class. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user please take the [Tour] where you will see that there should be only one question asked per question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this tool. It will take your iterator outputs
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/collect-values.htm